# Get data from the second JSON column

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON response. I need to parse it using PHP to output in the right place only the data from the second column (close) and the last (end). I previously parsed the answers in JSON, but here the data is separated by commas and this caused me difficulties. I will be grateful for any help in this matter)

```
{
"candles": {
    "metadata": {
        "open": {"type": "double"},
        "close": {"type": "double"},
        "high": {"type": "double"},
        "low": {"type": "double"},
        "value": {"type": "double"},
        "volume": {"type": "double"},
        "begin": {"type": "datetime", "bytes": 19, "max_size": 0},
        "end": {"type": "datetime", "bytes": 19, "max_size": 0}
    },
    "columns": ["open", "close", "high", "low", "value", "volume", "begin", "end"], 
    "data": [
        [1420, 1430.8, 1435, 1412, 1468004613.8, 1031760, "2021-04-21 00:00:00", "2021-04-21 23:59:59"],
        [1430.8, 1443.6, 1450, 1411.4, 1805714798.6, 1260392, "2021-04-22 00:00:00", "2021-04-22 23:59:59"],
        [1449.4, 1427.2, 1453, 1419.2, 1345626448.8, 941921, "2021-04-23 00:00:00", "2021-04-23 23:59:59"],
        [1428.6, 1408.8, 1433, 1402.4, 1797991005.6, 1272377, "2021-04-26 00:00:00", "2021-04-26 23:59:59"],
        [1413.4, 1406.4, 1427.8, 1400.6, 1956301672.2, 1383856, "2021-04-27 00:00:00", "2021-04-27 23:59:59"],
        [1410, 1395.8, 1411, 1376, 1803028517.8, 1296254, "2021-04-28 00:00:00", "2021-04-28 23:59:59"],
        [1405, 1401, 1419, 1381.8, 2038346551, 1458584, "2021-04-29 00:00:00", "2021-04-29 23:59:59"],
        [1404.8, 1358, 1408, 1353.2, 2178159392, 1588664, "2021-04-30 00:00:00", "2021-04-30 23:59:59"]
    ]
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

after you convert the object to an object using `json_decode`

```php
foreach ($candles->data as $row) {
    echo "close: " . $row[1] . "\n";
    echo "end: " . $row[count($row)-1] . "\n";
```

The code is very specific for the provided example and it works only if the "close" is always second, and "end" is always the last element.

Comment: you should try to find the index of close and end first,and then use it,that way it will never crash

Comment: I agree. However if I wrote that, I could write a validation of the values based on meta information provided as well. But I believe we are not here to write the whole code. Thanks for pointing out anyway